# Screen Snipping Program - Transparent Snipping Area

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm in the process of converting my successful screen snipping program from Tkinter to PYQT5. My question is how to create a fully transparent snipping area (a dynamically updating square region would be nice). The outside of the square will be semi-opaque. I've looked all over stack overflow and the internet and could not find an example of this (others are not a fully transparent drawing window). I've attached my code and a picture example of what I am looking for. The "SnippingWidget" is the class that does the snipping logic.

[image]
[image]

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence
from PIL import ImageGrab

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
        self.topMenu()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setWindowTitle('Lil Snippy')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('assets/lilSnippyIcon.png'))
        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 400, 300)
        self.show()

    def topMenu(self):
        menubar = self.menuBar()

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('File')
        saveAct = QAction(QIcon('assets/saveIcon.png'), 'Save', self)
        saveAsAct = QAction(QIcon('assets/saveAsIcon.png'), 'Save As', self)


        modeMenu = menubar.addMenu('Mode')
        snipAct = QAction(QIcon('assets/cameraIcon.png'), 'Snip', self)
        snipAct.setShortcut(QKeySequence('F1'))
        snipAct.triggered.connect(self.activateSnipping)
        videoAct = QAction(QIcon('assets/videoIcon.png'), 'Video', self)
        videoAct.setShortcut('F2')
        soundAct = QAction(QIcon('assets/audioIcon.png'), 'Sound', self)
        soundAct.setShortcut('F3')
        autoAct = QAction(QIcon('assets/automationIcon.png'), 'Automation', self)
        autoAct.setShortcut('F4')

        helpMenu = menubar.addMenu('Help')
        helpAct = QAction(QIcon('assets/helpIcon.png'), 'Help', self)
        aboutAct = QAction(QIcon('assets/aboutIcon.png'), 'About', self)

        fileMenu.addAction(saveAct)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAsAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(snipAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(videoAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(soundAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(autoAct)
        helpMenu.addAction(helpAct)
        helpMenu.addAction(aboutAct)

    def activateSnipping(self):
        print("yes")
        self.Snipper = SnippingWidget()
        application.hide()

class SnippingWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(SnippingWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;")
        self.setWindowOpacity(.2)
        self.showFullScreen()

        self.outsideSquareColor = 'red'
        self.squareThickness = 4

        self.startX = None
        self.startY = None
        self.endX = None
        self.endY = None
        self.begin = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end = QtCore.QPoint()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = self.begin
        self.startX = event.x()
        self.startY = event.y()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.destroy()
        x1 = min(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y1 = min(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
        x2 = max(self.begin.x(), self.end.x())
        y2 = max(self.begin.y(), self.end.y())
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))

        img.save('snips/testImage.png')
        application.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor('red'), self.squareThickness))
        trans = QtGui.QColor(255,255,255,255)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self.begin, self.end)
        qp.drawRect(rect)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `QPainterPath` to subtract the rectangle from the window with the selected rectangle:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from PIL import ImageGrab


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
        self.topMenu()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Lil Snippy")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("assets/lilSnippyIcon.png"))
        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 400, 300)

    def topMenu(self):
        menubar = self.menuBar()

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu("File")
        saveAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/saveIcon.png"), "Save", self)
        saveAsAct = QtWidgets.QAction(
            QtGui.QIcon("assets/saveAsIcon.png"), "Save As", self
        )

        modeMenu = menubar.addMenu("Mode")
        snipAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/cameraIcon.png"), "Snip", self)
        snipAct.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence("F1"))
        snipAct.triggered.connect(self.activateSnipping)
        videoAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/videoIcon.png"), "Video", self)
        videoAct.setShortcut("F2")
        soundAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/audioIcon.png"), "Sound", self)
        soundAct.setShortcut("F3")
        autoAct = QtWidgets.QAction(
            QtGui.QIcon("assets/automationIcon.png"), "Automation", self
        )
        autoAct.setShortcut("F4")

        helpMenu = menubar.addMenu("Help")
        helpAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/helpIcon.png"), "Help", self)
        aboutAct = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon("assets/aboutIcon.png"), "About", self)

        fileMenu.addAction(saveAct)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAsAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(snipAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(videoAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(soundAct)
        modeMenu.addAction(autoAct)
        helpMenu.addAction(helpAct)
        helpMenu.addAction(aboutAct)

        self.snipper = SnippingWidget()
        self.snipper.closed.connect(self.on_closed)

    def activateSnipping(self):
        self.snipper.showFullScreen()
        self.hide()

    def on_closed(self):
        self.snipper.hide()
        self.show()


class SnippingWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SnippingWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;")
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.2)

        self.outsideSquareColor = "red"
        self.squareThickness = 4

        self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start_point = event.pos()
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        r = QtCore.QRect(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=r.getCoords())
        img.save("snips/testImage.png")
        self.closed.emit()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(
            QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(self.outsideSquareColor), self.squareThickness)
        )
        trans = QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
        qp.setBrush(trans)

        outer = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        outer.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()))

        inner = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        inner.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized())
        r = outer - inner
        qp.drawPath(r)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = App()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

```
class SnippingWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    closed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SnippingWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.outsideSquareColor = "red"
        self.squareThickness = 4

        self.start_point = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.end_point = QtCore.QPoint()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start_point = event.pos()
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end_point = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        r = QtCore.QRect(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()
        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=r.getCoords())
        img.save("snips/testImage.png")
        self.closed.emit()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        trans = QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255)
        r = QtCore.QRectF(self.start_point, self.end_point).normalized()

        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        trans.setAlphaF(0.2)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        outer = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        outer.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()))
        inner = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        inner.addRect(r)
        r_path = outer - inner
        qp.drawPath(r_path)

        qp.setPen(
            QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(self.outsideSquareColor), self.squareThickness)
        )
        trans.setAlphaF(0)
        qp.setBrush(trans)
        qp.drawRect(r)
```

Comment: Hello eyllanesc, I appreciate your willingness to help me solve this issue. I Initially tried your solution against a black background and it appeared to work. Unfortunately the inside square is not fully transparent. The square still has some level of opaqueness against a white background.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is now a grey outside with a black inside. Both outside and inside are now 100% opaque.

Comment: @BrettLapierre what is your OS? and try removing `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)`. I have tested it on Linux. PyQt5 5.14.2 y Python 3.8.2 and it works correctly.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and It still does not work when removing that line. Both the inside and outside are still opaque.

Comment: @BrettLapierre try adding `self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")` and  `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

Comment: That was it! Hell yes! Thank you eyllanesc! Congrats on the bounty!